# Simulate folding paper using cloth modifier

Tags: physics

New User here. I seem to be having issues getting the cloth modifier to simulate paper folding over itself. At a point the cloth becomes stiff and does fold at a given vertex. I would like the paper to fall as it would under gravity in nature. Any help is appreciated, thanks. [image]

The vertices on the left side of the plane are pinned, but I would like the paper fold over itself somewhere along the line below.

[image]

Cloth Modifier Settings.

[image]

The book cover has also been given a collision modifier.

Comment: it won't help you but sometimes I wonder if it's not more convenient to simulate this kind of thing with bones so that you can really control the movement

Comment: Going off what @moonboots said, I have had excellent results using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul0Cm804STU